Two formulas for defining RMS and average of a waveform through a diode
A textbook problem where we have this given current waveform through a diode.
We are required to determine the maximum and RMS values of it [ Irms and Ip ] giving the average current= something amperes.
As a solution I used the RMS and average formulas considering the duty cycle δ.
In the solutions manual, the general relations of RMS and average were used, yet the final answers when comparing were different.
Why and when do you use which?




Is the waveform cropped? Typically, the textbook exercise would be for one cycle.  But what you presented is a bit more challenging.

@MOSFET       No, the waveform is exactly as it is in the textbook (it's the full image I've attached of it. Nothing is cropped or anything, just screenshotted and pasted it as it is !). And two things are required considering [ Iavg = a number Amps ]: 1) the peak (maximum) current Ip. And 2) the RMS value of the given waveform.

"Yet the final answers when comparing were different!" That shouldn't be surprising; the formulas used are different. That's the rule not the exception.

Let's start with why you chose "your" formulas. Do you know what they represent?

The formulas given in the solution manual are certainly correct. The formulas you use seem wrong or are approximations under certain conditions.

@Spencer What's the name of the textbook and its edition (and author(s))? Also, are you asking about the meaning of RMS? (It's all about power.) Finally, are you aware that you can analyze these kinds of questions using piecewise analysis?

What 'final answers' did you you get vs. the solutions manual? The equations for RMS look equivalent to me.

@Spencer - Hi, As commented above, where did those images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. You mentioned textbook & solution manual, but which ones? If the original sources are online & public, please [edit] the question & add each name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (or a private intranet) then give full details of the sources e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition.

RMS is, by definition, about power. For current or voltage it is about finding the equivalent that would dissipate the same power in a resistor if administered as a DC level. Since power is proportional to the square of current and/or the square of voltage, you can expect that this will involve squares of functions. Also note that the square of a value, whether positive or negative, is always positive. And that's what we would expect for power, regardless of whether the current or voltage was negative or positive, itself.
In general form, we are interested in the average power given any arbitrary period:
$$\begin{align*}
\overline{P}&=\frac1{t_1-t_0}\int_{t=t_0}^{t_1}P_t\:\text{d}t
\end{align*}$$
However, since we are just interested in the simpler case where a resistance is assumed there are two possible cases:
$$\begin{align*}
\overline{P}&=\frac1{t_1-t_0}\int_{t=t_0}^{t_1}P_t\:\text{d}t&\overline{P}&=\frac1{t_1-t_0}\int_{t=t_0}^{t_1}P_t\:\text{d}t
\\\\
&=\frac1{t_1-t_0}\int_{t=t_0}^{t_1}V_t\,I_t\:\text{d}t &&=\frac1{t_1-t_0}\int_{t=t_0}^{t_1}V_t\,I_t\:\text{d}t
\\\\
&=\frac{1}{t_1-t_0}R\int_{t=t_0}^{t_1}V_t^2\:\text{d}t &&=\frac1{t_1-t_0}\frac1{R}\int_{t=t_0}^{t_1}I_t^2\:\text{d}t
\\\\
\frac{\overline{P}}{R}&=\frac{1}{t_1-t_0}\int_{t=t_0}^{t_1}V_t^2\:\text{d}t &R\cdot\overline{P}&=\frac1{t_1-t_0}\int_{t=t_0}^{t_1}I_t^2\:\text{d}t
\\\\
V_{_\text{RMS}}&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{t_1-t_0}\int_{t=t_0}^{t_1}V_t^2\:\text{d}t} &I_{_\text{RMS}}&=\sqrt{\frac1{t_1-t_0}\int_{t=t_0}^{t_1}I_t^2\:\text{d}t}
\end{align*}$$
That summarizes the reasoning behind the term root-mean-square and why current and/or voltage is squared in the process of finding this mean DC-equivalent value from varying voltages and/or currents.
Of course, if either voltage or current is zero over the entire period from \$t_0\$ to \$t_1\$ then the result is zero, as well.
So you can segment the analysis (piecewise.) Analyze the part that isn't everywhere zero from the part that is. Set \$t_0=0\$ at the start of the actively changing period, \$t_1\$ at the end of that actively changing period and the start of the inactive period, and \$T_s\$ is the full period width. Then:
$$\begin{align*}
I_{_\text{RMS}}&=\sqrt{\frac1{T_s}\left[\int_{0}^{t_1}I_t^2\:\text{d}t + \int_{t_1}^{t_2=T_s}0\:\text{d}t\right]}
\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac1{T_s}\int_{0}^{t_1}I_t^2\:\text{d}t}
\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac1{T_s}\int_{0}^{t_1}I_p^2\sin^2\left(\omega\,t\right)\:\text{d}t}
\\\\
&=I_p\sqrt{\frac1{T_s}\int_{0}^{t_1}\sin^2\left(\omega\,t\right)\:\text{d}t}
\end{align*}$$
And that conforms to one of your equations above.
Continuing, you know (at least in the cases where you show pictures) that \$\omega\,t_1=\pi\$:
$$\begin{align*}
I_{_\text{RMS}}&=I_p\sqrt{\frac1{T_s}\int_{0}^{t_1}\sin^2\left(\omega\,t\right)\:\text{d}t}
\\\\
&=I_p\sqrt{\frac1{T_s}\left[\int_{0}^{t_1}\frac12\:\text{d}t-\int_{0}^{t_1}\cos\left(2\,\omega\,t\right)\:\text{d}t\right]}
\\\\
&=I_p\sqrt{\frac1{T_s}\left[\frac{t_1}{2}-\int_{0}^{t_1}\cos\left(2\,\omega\,t\right)\:\text{d}t\right]}
\\\\
&=I_p\sqrt{\frac1{T_s}\left[\frac{t_1}{2}-\frac{t_1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\left(2\,\phi\right)\:\text{d}\phi\right]}
\\\\
&=I_p\sqrt{\frac{t_1}{T_s}\left[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\left(2\,\phi\right)\:\text{d}\phi\right]}
\\\\
&=I_p\sqrt{\frac{t_1}{2\,T_s}}
\end{align*}$$
If \$\delta=\frac{t_1}{T_s}\$ then \$I_{_\text{RMS}}=I_p\sqrt{\frac{\delta}{2}}\$.
Which is another of your results.
So, in the first case with \$t_1=100\:\mu\text{s}\$ and \$T_s=\frac1{f_s=500\:\text{Hz}}=2\:\text{ms}\$ it follows that \$\delta=0.05\$.
Does any of this help to clarify?
